# VueJS: Reactive array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, reactive-programming, vue-reactivity

This may sound trivial, but it's not. So to summarize:

1. We have an array of objects (initially empty) stored in data.
2. When component is created, we add some objects to the array through custom fabric method.
3. Fabric method accepts base object and extends it with some additional props.
4. One of the props added by fabric method is a reference to data (`this.foo`).

The problem: resulting object is not reactive and does not reacts to `this.foo` change.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-framework-47me6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

What I have tried so far:

1. Using hack to return new `Vue(...)` to make object reactive (https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2660).
2. Using `$set` to set additional properties in the fabric method.

So the question is: how do we make object reactive?

P.S. I know using watchers/computed is the option, but not in this case. I want object to be reactive, not manually update whole array of objects.

Comment: You can try to replace an object in your array with the new one with all the neсessary props. This way the object turns into reactive one. All props in the object must exist before this object will be in the data section itself or in an array. Or you should use $set for all new props you are adding.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that when you do

```
{ foo: this.foo }
```

You're just passing the actual value stored in **this.foo** to the new objects foo property, which is 0 at the moment of instantiation and that's how javascript works with primitive values.

If you don't want to use computed properties or watchers, you can use an object instead of a primitive value which gets assigned by reference instead of by value.

So you could define your foo attribute in the data object like this:

```
foo: {val: 0}
```

Assign your value in addedProps like this

```
{foo: this.foo}
```

and increase the value like this

```
setInterval(() => this.foo.val++, 250);
```

Here's your code modified with the above https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-reactive-object-ybji5

Thanks,